# Using only certain pins on a sensor board

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensor

First of all I have to apologize if this has been answered before. I'm such a noob when it comes to electronics, I don't even know how to find an answer. I've tried, trust me.

So, I have bought XloBorg (https://www.piborg.org/xloborg) to attach to my GoPiGo 2 robokit. But as it went, it doesn't attach directly to the GoPiGo but to the Raspberry Pi. But it takes basically all of the pins in the Raspberry board, so I can't really attach it there.

So, ultimately I only need the magnetometer part of the XloBorg, I don't really care of the accelerometer. I checked the schematics and I can see which of the pins are for the magnetometer. So my question is, can I just use jumper wires, put them to the correct slots and get the magnetometer data? Or are these boards built so that I need to attach the whole thing for anything to work?

Cheers!

Comment: From the product page: "Uses ***only the I2C pins of the Raspberry Pi (and power)***, so you have lots of free pins to connect to PicoBorg or a LedBorg, or both!"

Comment: I read this and was actually the reason why I ended up buying this exact sensor. But it's a big block that connects to the Raspberry Pi, taking up essentially all of the pins available. Me, as a layman, didn't know if it's possible to just use jumper wires to connect the necessary pins, or if I need to connect everything for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [schematic](https://www.piborg.org/images/xloborg/XLoBorg_Schematic.pdf), if you only want to use the magnetometer, you need the following connections:

- GND
- +3.3V
- GPIO_0 (SDA)
- GPIO_1 (SCL)

[image]
[image]

You can use any one of the GND connections on the board. I typically use the closest to the power pin.

[image]

p.s.: since the other IC is also on the I2C bus, in case you want to use it in the future you do not have to make any additional connections.

p.p.s.: TL/DR, so, **yes**, you can just add 4 jumpers, you do not need all 26 connections..

Comment: Wow that was comprehensive, thanks a lot man! Ok, so essentially I'm just going to use the three top left connections and one ground? This should give me the data from both, the accelerometer AND the magnetometer?

Comment: Yes. It will give you the connection to both, but you only get data from the devices you call on I2C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [schematic of the XloBorg](https://www.piborg.org/images/xloborg/XLoBorg_Schematic.pdf)

The XloBorg only uses Gnd, 3.3V, and GPIO 0 and GPIO1.

All of the other pins on the Pi connector are available, and all of the Gnd and 3.3V connections can be used in parallel with other boards.

---

You cannot use fewer pins.  It appears to use I2C (a two wire serial protocol) to talk to the magnetometer and the accelerometer.  Both connections go to both chips.

You send commands to the chips, and the commands include an address.  Each chip only responds to commands on its address.

What you do is, you stack all of your boards on the Pi.  Other boards have two connectors, and so are stackable.

The XloBorg isn't stackable, so you put it on last.  It ends the stack.

Before you start stacking things, though, you must check which boards use which GPIO pins.  If other boards use GPIO 0 or GPIO 1, then you can't use them together with the XloBorg.

You must also check that the other boards are compatible with one another - GPIO conflicts and any thing else that might cause trouble if it is used for two different tasks.

Power can't cause conflicts, but you must make sure to stay below the limit for current that the Pi can deliver.

---

A quick look at the GoPiGo shows that it isn't stackable, either.

It also probably uses the same GPIO pins as the XLoBorg.

You can't use them together directly.

The GoPiGo has a connector you can use to connect to your XLoBorg.  You will have to use (short) jumper wires, and connect the two GPIO pins from the XLoBorg to two other wise unused GPIO pins.  You will need to check that the I2C library can use any desired pins.

I would first do some experiments with the XLoBorg without the GoPiGo board, and get used to working with it and make sure that it all works.

Then, I'd check the GoPiGo and see which GPIO pins are free.

Now, use jumpers to connect the XLoBorg to the Pi and use the GPIO pins you found free on the GoPiGo.

Modify your software, and get it working again.

Now, you can connect the XLoBorg to the connector on the GoPiGo.  It should work, and you should still full control over the GoPiGo.

Comment: Cheers man. In the GoPiGo there's the I2C port. Can I just use the jumper wires to connect the GPIOs to that port?
Here's a screenshot of the port description: http://imgur.com/a/aqBDJ
and here's a link to the page: https://www.dexterindustries.com/GoPiGo/learning/hardware-port-description/

Comment: Didn't see that.  Yes, if that is the same I2C port, then you can use it with the example code for the XLoBorg.  If not, you'll need to modify the example code.

Comment: Ok awesome. Coding's not a problem, just confused with the electronics side of all of this.